# SQLite: should I detach attached databases before a disconnect?

Tags: database, sqlite, perl

Should I detach an attached database before calling `$dbh->disconnect` or is it OK to omit the `DETACH` is such a case?

```
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:SQLite:dbname=my_db_1", ...

$dbh->do( "ATTACH DATABASE 'my_db_2' AS data" );
...
$dbh->do( "DETACH DATABASE data" );
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Comment: Well, you attach it each time you run the script, so detach is a good idea. Will it use the same name to attempt attach? if so, you should regardless get error `Database name is already in use`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To just close the database would be OK unless the main database is an in memory database and the journal mode is not WAL (Write Ahead Logging); *even then it would probably be extremely rare to encounter an issue*.  I think detach is provided for situations where you want to detach databases individually. So it's really a matter of personal choice unless dictated otherwise.

This is based upon the following :-

> Transactions involving multiple attached databases are atomic,
> assuming that the main database is not ":memory:" and the journal_mode
> is not WAL.
>
> If the main database is ":memory:" or if the journal_mode
> is WAL, then transactions continue to be atomic within each individual
> database file. But if the host computer crashes in the middle of a
> COMMIT where two or more database files are updated, some of those
> files might get the changes where others might not.

[ATTACH DATABASE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)

[This, from Tech On The Net](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/attach_database.php) states :-

> When the database connection is closed, the attached database will be
> automatically be detached.

and also

> To remove an attached database from your connection, use the DETACH
> DATABASE command or close the database connection.

Comment: When closing orderly, there are no active transactions.